# Reference issues in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, reference, dependencies

I have a Visual Studios Solution with two projects, one VB.net the other VC++. The VC++ project is a wrapper around Nvidia's Driver API called Nvapi. It is a nvapi.lib file and the associated header files. My code compiles and runs fine on my development machine but I tried copying the whole solution directory to another computer and running the executable it get an error saying the VC++ project dll or one of its dependences could not be found/loaded. It runs fine until the point that my code uses the nvapi wrapper but then crashes. I tried publishing the project so that it generated an installer and installing the program that way but I get the same error.

I decided to install VS2010 on the other computer and see if I could debug the  problem. After installing VS2010 I made a backup copy of the solution folder. I then opened the solution and compiled and ran the code fine. Now this is the part I really don't understand I went to the backed up copy of the solution (the one that was compiled on my development machine) navigated to the executable and ran it and it now worked fine. The only thing that I can think is that compiling the code copied the Nvapi.lib file to so system directory so that the exe works. Does anyone know what would cause this problem and how I would go about getting my code working on other machines without installing visual studio?

Comment: Please try using some paragraphs in your text.

Comment: VC++ is managed project? maybe install .NET Framework on other computer?

Comment: I don't think it's the .net framework because it is installed already.

Comment: How are you compiling the VC++ project? Is it MT or MD? Maybe you are missing the vcredist. Try running depends.exe on the dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common mistake is to copy the Debug build of a C++ project to another machine.  It won't be able to find the debug version of the runtime DLLs, like msvcr100d.dll.  Only ever deploy the Release build.

If you deployed the Release build and still have problems then you probably forgot to run the vcredist installer.  You can technically avoid this dependency when you only have a single DLL and an EXE that doesn't use the C++ standard library classes by compiling with /MT instead.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon if you have no idea what the missing dependency might be.

Comment: Thanks Hans! As always you are correct. I switching to release and rebuilding fixed my problem.